# Best practice to handle "changing" scripts in Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I have a list of allowed scripts (or allowed domains) in my `Content-Security-Policy` tag.
Included in this list are scripts used by our marketing team for tracking and targeting purpose.

My problem is that they regularly want to test new scripts (hence, new domains) and that forces me to update the CSP and release a new version of my app every time that happens.

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Allow any script?
Continue to update the CSP as needed?
Other?

Comment: You should keep separate development codebase  and production codebase, that way the marketing team can make tests with the development code as they wish.

Comment: They insist to do all their tests with our real users. So production environment is the only way. But I agree with you: you're not supposed to test in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, we ended up  removing all security regarding script origin.